# How to find an algorithm to calculate the best move for this graph based strategy game?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, game-theory

I'm prototyping a deterministic Risk like game. A player can move units from one node to a connected node if he has more than 1 unit the in origin node (must leave 1 unit behind). The player wins if he conquers the enemy's home node. Battles are settled by multiplying the node's defensive units by the defensive rate and then subtracting the attacking units; if the result is a number higher than 0 the attacking player conquers the node and the surviving units are moved to the conquered node. A node has a spawn rate that spawns units (belonging to the player controlling the node) every x turns.

I don't have much experience with graphs so I'm hoping I can get some help finding an algorithm that can calculate either the shortest possible winning move (if we are in a winning position) or the list of possible defensive moves that can be taken to avoid the other player win (if the other player has a shot at winning, but we can do something about it).

**Examples**

*[EDIT] On each node there are two numbers: the top number represents the number of units in that node, and the bottom number represents the spawn rate, which for this examples is always 0*

*Node indexes that I'll use bellow: [First level] 0,0 [Second level] 1,0; 1,1 [Third level] 2,0; 2,1, 2,2 ...*

*For this example the nodes are only connected from one level to the other; one diagonal away. This will not matter for the algorithm as every node will know which nodes it has connection with.*

*(1,0 is connected with: 0,0;  2,0; 2,1)*

*(2,1 is connected with: 1,0; 1,1; 3,1; 3,2), etc*

*Home node is 0,0*

[image: green-defensive-move]

*Red to move*

Red has two possible winning moves:

[Shortest] **3,0 -> 2,0 -> 1,0 -> 0,0 + 2,2 -> 1,1 -> 0,0**

*[Longest (should be ignored)] **3,0 -> 2,0 -> 1,0 -> 0,0 + 3,2 -> 2,1 / 2,2 -> 1,1 -> 0,0***

[image: green-defensive-move]

*Green to move*

Green has four moves he must choose from to avoid certain defeat:

**3,1 -> 2,0** | **3,1 -> 2,1** | **3,2 -> 2,1** | **2,2 -> 1,1**

The algorithm doesn't need to take into account the defensive rate and the spawn rate. I can figure that part out.

Hopefully this will be not too difficult for someone with graph related algorithm experience.

[EDIT]

To clarify something asked in the comments: The players take turns doing moves, sequentially, and may only move units (from one node to another) once per turn. The algorithm must take into account possible counter play by the opponent, and discard solutions where the opponent was able to defend in time.

It is important to chose the shortest winning move so that in cases where the opponent also has a a winning move (on another graph, an inverted triangle from the one depicted in the image, but with the "home node" colored red, belonging to the opponent), we can then compare the winning move sequence length and see who gets there first.

I don't want an algorithm to solve the entire game, only the sub game depicted in the example. For the entire game I'm using MCTS where other moves are considered, like which nodes to update, etc. This algorithm will be used for selection / expand, and possibly rollout in the MCTS, if I get something very fast.

Currently I'm looking into backwards induction, it is straight forward to implement, but it is quite expensive, even with lots of optimizations (discussion in the comments). So a more performant alternative would be great!

Comment: I didn't quite get what the two numbers represent inside the nodes in your examples. Can you please clarify that?

Comment: Perhaps the following will help: https://web.mit.edu/sp.268/www/nim.pdf

Comment: @nirshahar I've added an explanation (look for "\[EDIT\]") at the start of the examples section.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus That is interesting but I don't think it applies directly to my question. Maybe it can be adapted, but I don't see immediately how.

Comment: This reminds me of the video game _Phage Wars_. This could be seen as a turn-based version of that game, perhaps.

Comment: @joaoroque You can compute winning moves using backwards induction. A simple modification will compute shortest winning moves.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Nice find, that's a very nice algorithm that makes this problem so much simpler to solve! And it easily works for mandatory defensive moves aswell. I've done a simple implementation and, despite the fact that I can still improve its performance by orders of magnitude, it is a quite slow bruteforce algo. I'll be using it in the rollout phase of my MCTS and it would be great if it was as efficient as possible. If no one else answers with a better solution, I'll be answering with this solution once I have a more performant implementation.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus The state tree here seems to be huge; much larger than the game graph. So backwards induction really seems like a last resort method here.

Comment: @joaoroque Can a player attack multiple times on her turn, and are you asking for the fewest numbers of attacks that will make her win within a single turn; or are you taking into account counter-play by the other player?

Comment: @Arno I've clarified your questions in the post. Yes, it is a huge state tree. For the simple case where every player node has available moves and there is 2 opponent nodes in the graph, considering moves only in there direction of the home node), it has 70k game states, if I prune duplicates as soon as they appear it goes down to around 5k game states (so far pruning is slower than not pruning though, looking into that). An alternative would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Following Arno suggestion in the comments I've done a C# backwards induction implementation that includes dealing with state transposition. Here is the code for the runner class, the node class should be very straight forward to do. Hopefully it will help someone!

```csharp
public class BackwardsInduction
{
    private Func<IGameState, Move[]> moveSelectionFunc;
    private Func<IGameState, double[]> scoresFunc;
    private readonly double defaultScore;
    private readonly int nodeStartLevel;
    private readonly int nodeEndLevel;
    private List<List<BINode>> nodesPerLevel;

    private List<IGameState> gameStates;

    private Dictionary<int, BINode> visitedGameStatesHash;

    public BackwardsInduction(Func<IGameState, Move[]> moveSelectionFunc, Func<IGameState, double[]> scoresFunc, double defaultScore, int nodeStartLevel, int nodeEndLevel)
    {
        this.moveSelectionFunc = moveSelectionFunc;
        this.scoresFunc = scoresFunc;
        this.defaultScore = defaultScore;
        this.nodeStartLevel = nodeStartLevel;
        this.nodeEndLevel = nodeEndLevel;
        nodesPerLevel = new List<List<BINode>>();
        gameStates = new List<IGameState>();
        visitedGameStatesHash = new Dictionary<int, BINode>();
    }


    public BINode RunGetRootNode(IGameState rootState, int? maxDepth)
    {
        var rootNode = new BINode(playerJustMoved: rootState.PlayerToMove, defaultScore: defaultScore);
        nodesPerLevel.Add(new List<BINode>() { rootNode });
        Run(rootState, rootNode, maxDepth);
        if (rootNode == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        BackFillScores();

        return rootNode;
    }

    public void Run(IGameState currentState, BINode currentNode, int? maxDepth, int currentLevel = 0)
    {
        var availableMoves = moveSelectionFunc(currentState);
        if (availableMoves.Length == 0)
        {
            currentNode.Scores = scoresFunc(currentState);
        }
        if (nodesPerLevel.Count <= currentLevel)
        {
            nodesPerLevel.Add(new List<BINode>());
        }
        if (maxDepth == null || currentLevel < maxDepth.Value)
        {
            foreach (var move in availableMoves)
            {
                var newState = currentState.Clone() as IGameState;
                var thisNodePlayerJustMoved = newState.PlayerToMove;
                newState.DoMove(move);
                var gameStateHash = GetGameStateHashCode(newState);
                if (visitedGameStatesHash.TryGetValue(gameStateHash, out BINode transposedNode))
                {
                    currentNode.AddTransposedNode(transposedNode);
                    continue;
                }

                var newNode = currentNode.AddChildGetNode(move, thisNodePlayerJustMoved, newState);
                visitedGameStatesHash.Add(gameStateHash, newNode);

                nodesPerLevel[currentLevel].Add(newNode);

                Run(newState, newNode, maxDepth, currentLevel + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public void BackFillScores()
    {
        for (int i = nodesPerLevel.Count - 2; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            foreach (var node in nodesPerLevel[i])
            {
                if (node.ChildNodes.Any())
                {
                    node.Scores = node.ChildNodes.MinObject(x => x.Scores[x.PlayerJustMoved.Id]).Scores;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private int GetGameStateHashCode(IGameState gameState)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            for (int level = nodeStartLevel; level <= nodeEndLevel; level++)
            {
                var levelNodes = gameState.Nodes[level];
                for (int index = 0; index < levelNodes.Length; index++)
                {
                    hash = hash * 23 + levelNodes[index].GetSimplifiedHash();
                }
            }
            hash = hash * 23 + gameState.PlayerToMove.Id;
            hash = hash * 23 + gameState.PlayerToMove.MoveCount;
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

This is not the optimal solution for my scenario because it has to process a huge state tree and is quite expensive. But it solves my problem for now and outputs the correct result.